# Images with excerpt function

Tags: images, excerpt

I got this great excerpt function that keeps my paragraphs in tact. Works great btw.

```
 function pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($text) {
global $post;
$raw_excerpt = $text;
if ( '' == $text ) {
    $text = get_the_content('');

    $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );

    $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
    $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);

    //Add the allowed HTML tags separated by a comma.
    $allowed_tags = '<p>,<a>,<em>,<strong>';  
    $text = strip_tags($text, $allowed_tags);

    //Change the excerpt word count.
    $excerpt_word_count = 105; 
    $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count); 

    //Change the excerpt ending.
    $excerpt_end = ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&hellip;' . __( 'Read more about this article <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'pietergoosen' ) . '</a>'; 
    $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end);

    $words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    if ( count($words) > $excerpt_length ) {
        array_pop($words);
        $text = implode(' ', $words);
        $text = $text . $excerpt_more;
    } else {
        $text = implode(' ', $words);
    }
}
return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```

To show the first image with the excerpt, I use the old function

```
    function pietergoosen_get_first_image() {
    global $post, $posts;
$first_img = '';
if(preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $post->post_content, $matches)){
$first_img = $matches [1] [0];
} 
    return $first_img;
}
```

This also works great.

The question now is (I'm not a coder at all), is there a way and how to change the excerpt code I supplied to automatically display the first image without needing more functions. Any code will be highly appreciated

Comment: I don't understand the question. You have two functions which you say work correctly, so what are you asking? You want to know how to combine the functions? Why? To achieve what end?

Comment: Was just curious to know if you can somehow integrate these functions into one. Trying to clean up some of my codes in my child theme

Comment: [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Getting the image and truncating text are two different operations, they should kept separated.

Comment: Can you combine them? Probably. But ___why___? It isn't possible to solve a problem without knowing the details of the problem. And as @toscho has noted, it may not even be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone that is looking for an excerpt that keeps images etc in tact without using the first image function, here is the code

```
    function pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt($text) {
global $post;
$raw_excerpt = $text;
    if ( '' == $text ) {

        $text = get_the_content('');
        $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
        $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
        $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);

            //Add the allowed HTML tags separated by a comma.
            $allowed_tags = array(
            'head', 'title', 'base', 'link', 'meta', 'style', 'script', 'noscript', 'body', 'section', 'nav',
            'article', 'aside', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'header', 'footer', 'address', 'main', 'p', 'hr',
            'pre', 'blockquote', 'ol', 'ul', 'li', 'dl', 'dt', 'dd', 'figure', 'figcaption', 'div', 'a', 'em', 'strong',
            'small', 's', 'cite', 'q', 'dfn', 'abbr', 'data', 'time', 'code', 'var', 'samp', 'kbd', 'sub', 'sup', 'i', 'b',
            'u', 'mark', 'ruby', 'rt', 'rp', 'bdi', 'bdo', 'span', 'br', 'wbr', 'ins', 'del', 'img', 'iframe', 'embed',
            'object', 'param', 'video' ,'audio', 'source', 'track', 'canvas', 'map', 'area', 'svg', 'math', 'table',
            'caption', 'colgroup', 'col', 'tbody', 'thead', 'tfoot', 'tr', 'td', 'th', 'form', 'fieldset', 'legend', 'label',
            'input', 'button', 'select', 'datalist', 'optgroup', 'option', 'textarea', 'keygen', 'output', 'progress', 'meter',
            'details', 'summary', 'menuitem', 'menu'
            );

            $tag_string = '<' . implode('><', $allowed_tags) . '>';

        $text = strip_tags($text, $tag_string);

        //Set the excerpt word count and only break after sentence is complete.
            $excerpt_word_count = 75;
            $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', $excerpt_word_count); 
            $tokens = array();
            $excerptOutput = '';
            $count = 0;

            // Divide the string into tokens; HTML tags, or words, followed by any whitespace
            preg_match_all('/(<[^>]+>|[^<>\s]+)\s*/u', $text, $tokens);

            foreach ($tokens[0] as $token) { 

                if ($count >= $excerpt_word_count && preg_match('/[\?\.\!]\s*$/uS', $token)) { 
                // Limit reached, continue until ? . or ! occur at the end
                    $excerptOutput .= trim($token);
                    break;
                }

                // Add words to complete sentence
                $count++;

                // Append what's left of the token
                $excerptOutput .= $token;
            }

        $text = trim(force_balance_tags($excerptOutput));

            $excerpt_end = ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . '&nbsp;&raquo;&nbsp;' . sprintf(__( 'Read more about: %s &nbsp;&raquo;', 'pietergoosen' ), get_the_title()) . '</a>'; 
            $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . $excerpt_end); 

            $pos = strrpos($text, '</');

        // Add 'Read more' text inside last HTML tag
        $text = substr_replace($text, $excerpt_end, $pos, 0);

    }
    return apply_filters('wp_trim_excerpt', $text, $raw_excerpt);
}

remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'pietergoosen_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
```